# Javascript Object Constructors with Different Prototypes Confusion

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I was looking into Javascript objects and prototypes, as far as I knew, the two ways of defining constructors ends up with similar results.

For example in this code the same exact constructors are defined in 2 different ways yet they end up with different prototype values:

```
var PersonOne = function () {};

function PersonTwo(){};

var p1 = new PersonOne();
var p2 = new PersonTwo();

console.log(p1.constructor.prototype);
console.log(p2.constructor.prototype);
```

result:

```
Object {}
PersonTwo {}
```

Obviously I was wrong about that and defining the constructor like in PersonOne results in a constructor who's prototype is Object. And that would affect inheritance. But the question is, what is the reason for such a different result?

I think the issue might be due to the fact that PersonOne function gets defined on run-time while PersonTwo on parse-time? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `PersonOne` has been assigned the result of an *anonymous function expression*.  The named variable is just an *alias* for that function, but the constructor function itself has no `.name` property.

If instead you had declared it:

```
var PersonOne = function MyPersonOne() {};
```

then the prototype of an object created as a `new PersonOne` would be `MyPersonOne`.

This is important - it ensures that you can't create objects of arbitrary "type" just by creating an alias to a constructor.  The "type" of the object must be the same as the (real) name of the constructor function.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks for the clarification now I get it :)